# How do I change the elements of url and open it in new tab with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Current URL

```
https://example.com/render.php#url=[Media_URL]
```

I want to modify the current url so that when I click a button, it will open a new tab on the browser with the modified URL:

```
https://example.com/convert/index.php?url=[Media_URL]&&ftype=mp3
```

`[Media_URL]` is a reusable variable.

How can I do that in JavaScript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `Media_URL` a Javascript variable?

Comment: Is it safe to assume this is a question concerning HTML?  The opening in a new tab functionality is in the markup realm rather than the javascript realm in most cases, but you could be using a component based interpreter like REACT.js or Vue.js.  Also, how are you accessing the current URL.  Is it just a string in javascript or is it in the DOM?

Comment: @dustytrashIt is a URL for example `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEOeTWXefyE`

Comment: @Joseph I'm new to this community and I'm not sure about marking the question. I'm learning about javascript so I have marked it. Sorry if this does not fit.

Comment: @NguyenHongThe Not a problem at all, and welcome to the community.  I can edit the question and add the tag too. As you get used to the site, you'll know which tags are needed and which ones are not.  I just didn't want to add a tag that was incorrect, so I decided to ask.  So is there HTML involved or is this strictly javascript?

Comment: @Joseph Yes, after reviewing, I think it includes both HTML and Javascript. Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button id="myButton">
</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    var Media_URL = window.location.href.split("#url=")[1];
    var url = 'https://example.com/convert/index.php?url=' + Media_URL + '&&ftype=mp3';
    window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
};
```

**Explnation**

To get a value from the URL in Javascript, use `window.location.href`.

Then you can parse it with `.split("#url=")`, creating an array, the second element `[1]` will have the right part of the URL, which in your example contains Media_URL.

To open in a new tab, use `window.open(url, '_blank')`

Answer (score 0):

To get the current `url` you can use: `window.location.href`. To redirect to a new tab read the documentation of `window.open()` at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use tag `<button>` and `<a>` nested, with `target="_blank"` in  attribute for new tab.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><button>.</button></a>
```

or

```
 <a href="#" class="btn">.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated use `window.open()` but you need to be aware that the user's browser settings may block the window from opening.

```
let blocked = false
try {
  const nu = window.open('https://google.com', '_blank');
  if (nu === null) {  // built-in blocking makes this null
    blocked = true;
  }
} catch (ex) {  // popup-blocking plugins make it raise an error
  blocked = true;
}

if (blocked) {
  alert('blocked!');
}

console.log(blocked)
// If it returns null or an error it's blocked
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I will try it.